# Why is this ActiveRecord Query NOT ambiguous?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With Rails 3, I am using the following kind of code to query a MySQL database:

```
MyData.joins('JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM sellers) AS Q
  ON seller_id = Q.id').
  select('*').
  joins('JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM users) AS T 
  ON user_id = T.id'). 
  select("*").each do |record| 
  #..........
```

Then, a bit further down, I try to access a "name" with this code: (note that both sellers and users have a name column).

```
str = record.name
```

This line is giving me a "user name" instead of a "seller name", but shouldn't it give nothing?  Since I joined multiple tables with a name column, shouldn't I be get an error like "column 'name' is ambiguous"?  Why isn't this happening?

And by the way, the code behaves the same way whether I include that first "select('*')" line or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's no reason to call `select` twice - only the last call will actually be used.  Secondly, you should not be using `select("*")`, because the SQL database (and Rails) will not rename the ambiguous columns for you.  Instead, use explicit naming for the extra columns that you need:

```
MyData.joins('JOIN (SELECT..) AS Q ON ...', 'JOIN (SELECT...) AS T ON ...').
       select('my_datas.*, T.name as t_name, Q.name as q_name').
       each do |record|
  # do something
end
```

Because of this, there's no reason to make a subquery in your JOIN statements:

```
MyData.joins('JOIN sellers AS Q ON ...', 'JOIN users AS T ON ...').
```

And finally, you should already have `belongs_to` associations set up for `seller` and `user`.  That would mean that you can just do this:

```
MyData.joins(:seller, :user).
       select("my_datas.*, sellers.name as seller_name, users.name as user_name").
       each do |record|
  # do something
end
```

Now you can call `record.seller_name` and `record.user_name` without any ambiguity.